# svn backup issues -- load from dump yields incomplete copy

Tags: linux, svn, backup, redhat

For reasons that are not important here, I've been tasked with splitting a Subversion repository into two pieces. The following URL was sent me as evidence that the procedure was fairly straightforward:

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/11/02/splitting-a-svn-repository/

However, while I've followed the steps therein, I keep winding up, after the **svnadmin load** steps, with repository splits that are missing approximately half of the subdirectories that are in the original repository (I have *not* altered the original, yet).

Somewhere, probably in another Stackoverflow thread, I read about the hotcopy utility. It sounded promising, but when I tried to employ this I discovered that I'd need to upgrade the repository first.

And so I feel a bit stuck: I can't use hotcopy until I upgrade, but I don't want to upgrade without a backup -- that is, without feeling confident I can restore the repository from some unforeseen disaster ... and so far it looks like I can't do a restore (using svnadmin dump and load) without losing big chunks of the repository.

I am not sure what the culprit is, or how to begin to untangle the issue. Any tips would be welcome. For what it is worth I am working on a Red Hat 8 (e.g. Linux) system.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a business case for splitting the repository?

Splitting a Subversion repository is a complicated admin operation. If possible, it's better to keep the repository is is. And splitting a repository is definitely not the operation which you want to perform as a step in your backup or restore procedures. I'm assuming that your question is related to backups because of its title and the [backup] tag.

> I read about the hotcopy utility. It sounded promising, but when I
> tried to employ this I discovered that I'd need to upgrade the
> repository first.

`svnadmin hotcopy` won't help you split the repository. This command is designed for copy and backup purposes and creates a copy of the repository (without splitting the revision history).

> However, while I've followed the steps therein, I keep winding up,
> after the svnadmin load steps, with repository splits that are missing
> approximately half of the subdirectories that are in the original
> repository (I have not altered the original, yet).

The instructions you are referring to make use the the `svndumpfilter` utility. It requires you to carefully consider all the paths you need to enter into `--include` and `--exclude` command-line options. Perhaps you are missing some data in the new repository because you didn't include some of the required paths. You can find more information about using `svndumpfilter` and its caveats in [SVNBook | Filtering Repository History](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering).

Instead of using `svndumpfilter`, try the [`--include` and `--exclude` options supported by the `svnadmin dump` command starting from SVN 1.10.](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.10#dump-include-exclude). They don't have the caveats of `svndumpfilter` and are less "path-sensitive".

But anyways, filtering history of a repository in process of backing it up is not a good idea. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The business case here is that a former employee who was responsible for a huge project has agreed to keep working on it as a volunteer -- so: she no longer has (nor should have) permissions to work with the full repository, but she'd like to continue to be able to check in changes to her specific project. The thought was if we could split out the part she'd need to work with and have it be accessible to a separate UNIX group, that would make this possible. I am concerned about backup because before attempting any changes to the repository, I want to be able to 'save' it as it is.

Comment: @GlennBecker why don’t you configure user permissions in your repositories so that she has access only to her specific project without any access to other projects? SVN supports path-based authorization. Granular access control is built into SVN.

Comment: Didn't know that! Looking at docs now. Thank you (one thing I'm encountering is that this repo was created with an older version of svn ... hoping that won't get in the way here).

Comment: I'm back where I was. The SVN path-based authorization assumes one is running svnserve (or Apache) to serve the repository across the network. We're using neither (this was set up by others, years ago, so I can't answer questions re: why this, or anything else was done the way it was). Still trying, and still getting only partial results. Thanks bahrep for your help / suggestions.

Comment: @GlennBecker It is technically possible to use a Subversion repository without any server (svnserve or apache) and access it via the file:// protocol (I assume that's your current configuration). However, it is strongly this approach is discouraged, especially when you have multiple users accessing this repository. You need to think about deploying an actual server to host your repositories. VisualSVN Server has everything you need, but it can be installed only on Windows.

Comment: I did find myself wondering whether I could simply "turn on" svnserve. I'm sure it's more complicated than that! This was all set up in ... maybe 2008 and I had no involvement. Paying for that now, but I guess the positive side is I'm learning a lot.